# Storing binary objects in SQL Server with LINQ

Tags: sql-server, linq, serialization

I'm trying to do the same thing as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118296/c-how-would-you-store-arbitrary-objects-in-an-sql-server), but am having problems.

Can you share with me how you prepared your objects prior to inserting and updating the database?

I have a `List<myObject>` that I want to store as a `VarBinary(max)` in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow. If one of the answers below helped answer you question you should mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to convert your `List<object>` to a `byte[]`.  You don't need Linq specifically but I assume you are using Linq To Sql?  Before storing your object in the property that should contain the binary you need to convert it to a `byte[]`.  Here is some example code to do what you need ([Source Link](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3897)):

```
// Convert an object to a byte array
private byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
{
    if(obj == null)
        return null;
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
    return ms.ToArray();
}

// Convert a byte array to an Object
private Object ByteArrayToObject(byte[] arrBytes)
{
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
    BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
    memStream.Write(arrBytes, 0, arrBytes.Length);
    memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    Object obj = (Object) binForm.Deserialize(memStream);
    return obj;
}
```